# Binding multiple lists to as specific datagridcombobox column

Tags: wpf, list, xaml, binding, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a data grid that has 2 columns
One is a DataGridText
Second is a DataGridComboBox
When I load the data both columns are filed, but when I click on the second one, I want to have a combobox that will load the data from the second list
So the lists are like this

public ObservableCollection PriorityRuleList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection();

```
public ObservableCollection<int> RulePriorityDefaultList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<int>() { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 };
```

The PriorityRule class is like this:

```
public class PriorityRule
{
    public PriorityRule(RecipientSource recipientSource)
    {
        RuleType = recipientSource.Name;
        Priority = recipientSource.Priority;
    }
    public PriorityRule() { }
    public string RuleType { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
    public RecipientSource RecipientSource { get; set; }

}
```

The .XAML file is like this:

```
<DataGrid
                    x:Name="PriorityRulesGrid"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                    CanUserAddRows="False"
                    GridLinesVisibility="All"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    IsReadOnly="False"
                    RowHeight="32"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
                    ItemsSource="{Binding PriorityRuleList}"
                    ColumnWidth="*" >
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="{texts:VRI Rule type}"  
                                                    Binding="{Binding RuleType}"
                                                    IsReadOnly="True"
                                                    Width="*"/>
                                <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="{texts:VRI Priority}" 
                                                        Width="*"
                                    SelectedValuePath="Priority"
                                    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Priority}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="Priority">

                                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.PriorityRuleList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                                        </Style>
                                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.RulePriorityDefaultList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>    
                   </DataGrid>
```

My question is:
How should I load the second list when click on the combobox in the second column. The first list is loaded when the window appears, so it is ok, but I need to choose from a combobox the priority, so I could't load the second list (the int type) in order to choose from there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Look like you are trying to assign two different types of sources to `DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemSource`.  keeping two sources ok, but make sure Property `Priority` exists. Otherwise, evaluation of `SelectedValuePath` and `DisplayMemberPath` will fail.

Create a class PriorityX with a property `Priority`

```
public class PriorityX
        {
            public int Priority { get; set; }

        }

    // assing your default values into this collection
    public ObservableCollection<PriorityX> RulePriorityDefaultList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<PriorityX>();
```

in XAML

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!--load RulePriorityDefaultList as a static resource-->
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="RulePriorityDefaultList" Source="{Binding RulePriorityDefaultList}" />
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid
                x:Name="PriorityRulesGrid"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                CanUserAddRows="False"
                GridLinesVisibility="All"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                IsReadOnly="False"
                RowHeight="32"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                ItemsSource="{Binding PriorityRuleList}"
                ColumnWidth="*">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Rule type"
                                                Binding="{Binding RuleType}"
                                                IsReadOnly="True"
                                                Width="*" />
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Priority"
                               Width="*"
                               SelectedValuePath="Priority"
                               SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Priority}"
                               DisplayMemberPath="Priority"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RulePriorityDefaultList }}">
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

you may use your existing class too.

```
//assing your default values into this collection
public ObservableCollection<PriorityRule> RulePriorityDefaultList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<PriorityRule>();
```

Comment: @Ștefan Blaga, Does this suggestion help you?

Comment: No, I didn't even made it compile. DataGridComboBoxColumn doesn't have ItemsSource attribute. And I cannot assign default values to the RulePriorityDefaultList, because using this list I load the data in grid

Comment: Refer here, [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn.itemssource?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_DataGridComboBoxColumn_ItemsSource)

Comment: Sorry, I missed the end of the sentence in code. If I do it like above, the data will not be loaded. Then I need to create the default list with the priorities